# QFileDialog не фильтрует файлы по расширению

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qfiledialog

Есть шаблон для загрузки файлов. Мне нужно загружать картинки, причем с расширением только **`.png`**. 
Соответственно, нужно и в диалоговом окне отображать только такие файлы, а **`остальные - скрывать`**.

Подскажите, что я написал не правильно?

Прописал код:

```
imagePathTuple =

 QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        None, 
    'Выбрать изображение', 
    '*', 
    "Image files (*.png)"
)
```

В конце вроде как фильтр по расширению `"Image files (*.png)"`, но в окне всё равно все файлы что есть в папке.

[image: показаны все файлы, а нужно только png]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `QFileDialog` позволяет пользователю перемещаться по файловой системе,
чтобы выбрать один или несколько файлов или каталог.

```
QString QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
  QWidget *parent = nullptr, 
  const QString &caption = QString(), 
  const QString &dir = QString(), 
  const QString &filter = QString(), 
  QString *selectedFilter = nullptr, 
  QFileDialog::Options options = Options()
)
```

`getOpenFileName` это удобная `статическая функция`, которая возвращает существующий файл,
выбранный пользователем.
Если пользователь нажимает ***Отмена***, возвращается пустая строка.

Функция создает модальный файловый диалог с заданным родительским виджетом.
Если parent не равен nullptr, диалог будет показан по центру родительского виджета.

Рабочий каталог диалогового окна файла будет установлен на `dir`.
Если `dir` включает имя файла, он будет выбран.
Отображаются только файлы, соответствующие заданному фильтру.
Выбранный фильтр установлен на `selectedFilter`.
Параметры `dir`, `selectedFilter` и `filter` могут быть пустыми строками.

**В `Windows` и `macOS` эта статическая функция будет использовать собственное диалоговое окно файла, а не `QFileDialog`**.

В вашем случае:

```
imagePathTuple = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
  None,                                       # QWidget *parent = nullptr,
  'Выбрать изображение',                      # const QString &caption = QString(),
  '*',                                        # const QString &dir = QString(),    <<<---- !!!            
  "Image files (*.png)"                       # const QString &filter = QString(), 
)
```

Рабочий каталог `dir -> '*'` интерпретируется как выбрать все файлы и перебивает `filter`.

**Оставьте это поле пустым или укажите рабочий каталог.**

```
imagePathTuple = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
  None,                    
  'Выбрать изображение',   
  '',                                         #  <<<---- !!!   
  # или так:
  # "/home",                                  #  <<<---- !!!   
  "Image files (*.png)"   
)
```

Comment: Благодаря вам я обучаюсь быстрее чем мог бы)
Спасибо) Чем могу отблагодарить? Рекомендации сервиса я учитываю, отмечаю ответы полезными и реальным решением.

Comment: @Павел рад что мои ответы вам помогают, не забывайте в своих вопросах приводить минимально-воспроизводимые примеры.

Comment: могу я вам предложить работу за деньги? Если да, то как можно связаться?

Comment: Ciberpol@mail.ru
Спасибо.